# get middle of a string - remove left and right

Tags: php, string

I have this string:

```
"cursor:pointer; background:url(http://maps.google.com/staticmap?center=38.7376583333,-9.1658583333&maptype=satellite&zoom=14&size=300x300&key=ABQIAAAAvQ9c8pqKsi8K2dzb7UM9MhS13VDmd70a9rmDETSCgg2iXt3XnhQSnX4vFKfWO-3vdWNV5HHBnSLWLQ&sensor=true&hl=pt) no-repeat"
```

and i want to remove the Latitude and Longitude. So i want to cut the left of the string until `"center="` and right starting `"&maptype="`.

So I've cut the left part, but now i don't know how to cut the right part.

EDIT:

```
$h1['style']=$html->find('td.sendGps',0)->style;

$string=$h1['style'];  // i have this, which does not work like the $string=""cursor:pointer; background:url(http://maps.google.com/staticmap?center=38.7376583333,-9.1658583333&maptype=satellite&zoom=14&size=300x300&key=ABQIAAAAvQ9c8pqKsi8K2dzb7UM9MhS13VDmd70a9rmDETSCgg2iXt3XnhQSnX4vFKfWO-3vdWNV5HHBnSLWLQ&sensor=true&hl=pt) no-repeat""
$inicio = "?center=";
$fim = "&maptype=";

$b = substr($string, strpos($string, $inicio) + 8);
```

Comment: wouldn't it be better to use regexp?

Comment: Check out `strrpos()`. It's the same as `strpos()` but searches from the end of the string.

Comment: I left the double-quotes in there, but I don't think you actually are dealing with those in reality, right?

Comment: Proposition Joe, what happened to you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be more than you want to go through, but it's possible to extract and decompose the URL and query string from the URL:

```
<?php

$data = "cursor:pointer; background:url(http://maps.google.com/staticmap?center=38.7376583333,-9.1658583333&maptype=satellite&zoom=14&size=300x300&key=ABQIAAAAvQ9c8pqKsi8K2dzb7UM9MhS13VDmd70a9rmDETSCgg2iXt3XnhQSnX4vFKfWO-3vdWNV5HHBnSLWLQ&sensor=true&hl=pt) no-repeat";

$url = substr($data, strpos($data, 'url(') + 4);
$url = parse_url(substr($url, 0, strpos($url, ') ')));

print_r($url);

$query = explode('&', $url['query']);
$querypairs = array();

for ($i = 0, $l = count($query); $i < $l; $i++) {
    $pair = explode('=', $query[$i]);
    $querypairs[$pair[0]] = $pair[1];
}

print_r($querypairs);

?>
```

http://codepad.org/xRZ3zEcU

Now, if you really wanted to do that so that you could then recompose into a CSS definition again for later use, you could reverse it, but I would probably try to decompose the CSS in a similar fashion. Or, as a lesser means, just do a `str_replace()` on the prior definition and replace the `$url` after rebuilding the resultant URL with [`http_build_query()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php).

And if you really, really just don't care about the rest of it...

```
<?php

$data = "cursor:pointer; background:url(http://maps.google.com/staticmap?center=38.7376583333,-9.1658583333&maptype=satellite&zoom=14&size=300x300&key=ABQIAAAAvQ9c8pqKsi8K2dzb7UM9MhS13VDmd70a9rmDETSCgg2iXt3XnhQSnX4vFKfWO-3vdWNV5HHBnSLWLQ&sensor=true&hl=pt) no-repeat";

$center = substr($data, strpos($data, '?center=') + 8);
$center = substr($center, 0, strpos($center, '&'));

print_r($center);

?>
```

http://codepad.org/RiJHTX6p

**EDIT**: Those last minute updates always get you... Fixed.

Do the `substr()` match on the beginning/end on separate lines, so the second `strpos()` is relative the result of the first match. I think this way of doing it is a lot easier to understand, and the performance (I believe) should not be significantly different. Additionally, it will handle different orders of the query string pairs, because the second, "relevant" `&` check is first after the key. Otherwise, I believe you would be better off decomposing the query string.

And if you'd like a `mid()` function like in VB and VBA, you can use:

```
<?php

function mid($start, $end, $str) {
    $str = substr($str, strpos($str, $start) + strlen($start));
    return substr($str, 0, strpos($str, $end));
}

$data = "cursor:pointer; background:url(http://maps.google.com/staticmap?center=38.7376583333,-9.1658583333&maptype=satellite&zoom=14&size=300x300&key=ABQIAAAAvQ9c8pqKsi8K2dzb7UM9MhS13VDmd70a9rmDETSCgg2iXt3XnhQSnX4vFKfWO-3vdWNV5HHBnSLWLQ&sensor=true&hl=pt) no-repeat";

print_r(mid('?center=', '&', $data));

?>
```

http://codepad.org/2rjmC4PL

Comment: +1 for parse_str rather than the tedious explode stuff others are suggesting.

Comment: Thanks Jared Farrish. That worked. Why do you said that about my double quotes?

Comment: @PropositionJoe - I was just verifying that double-quotes weren't part of the string you needed to deal with. If it was, first thing I'd do is remove them from the string. If not, I wouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

`substr` takes three params, the last being the length of the returned string (from the start position).

So in your case, you would use `$b = substr($string, strpos($string, $inico) + 8, 27);`.

However if you are manipulating strings like this, it would probably pay (in less headaches when the URL style changes) to `parse_url` and `explode` to extract the parameters.

Here's an exapmple:

```
$originalString = "cursor:pointer; background:url(http://maps.google.com/staticmap?center=38.7376583333,-9.1658583333&maptype=satellite&zoom=14&size=300x300&key=ABQIAAAAvQ9c8pqKsi8K2dzb7UM9MhS13VDmd70a9rmDETSCgg2iXt3XnhQSnX4vFKfWO-3vdWNV5HHBnSLWLQ&sensor=true&hl=pt) no-repeat";

$url = substr($originalString, strpos($originalString, "url(") + 4);
$url = substr($url, 0, strrpos($url, ")"));

$params = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
$paramArray = explode("&", $params);
```

`$paramArray` now contains a name-value-pair of the URL's GET parameters.

Comment: but the length of LAT and LON aren't always the same.

Comment: i need to have the strpost of &maptype

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = "cursor:pointer; background:url(http://maps.google.com/staticmap?center=38.7376583333,-9.1658583333&maptype=satellite&zoom=14&size=300x300&key=ABQIAAAAvQ9c8pqKsi8K2dzb7UM9MhS13VDmd70a9rmDETSCgg2iXt3XnhQSnX4vFKfWO-3vdWNV5HHBnSLWLQ&sensor=true&hl=pt) no-repeat";
$str = explode('center=', $str);
$str = explode('&maptype=', $str[1]);
$str = $str[0];
echo $str;
```

Fiddle:
http://www.phpfiddle.org/main/code/6rs-5hh

Additionally if you want to get the LAT and LONG separately afterwards, use this code after you assign them to `$str`:

```
$str = explode(',', $str);
$lat = $str[0];
$long = $str[1];
echo 'Lattitude ' . $lat . ' and Longtitude ' . $long;
```

Comment: it works if i define the string like you in $str, but i get my string like:  $h1['style']=$html->find('td.sendGps',0)->style;
and then i do $str = $h1['style'] and doesn't work.It says "Notice...array to string conversion" But the echo $str and echo $h1['style'] have equal results.

Comment: You should try `var_dump($str);` before trying to do anything with it to see if you are working with a string or an array. You can't explode arrays using the code above. You have to take the string inside them first.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/c1aCjcvJ still does not work. It's a problem with beeing a array

Comment: The result: string(281) "cursor:pointer; background:url(http://maps.google.com/staticmap?center=38.7376583333,-9.1658583333&maptype=satellite&zoom=14&size=300x300&key=ABQIAAAAvQ9c8pqKsi8K2dzb7UM9MhS13VDmd70a9rmDETSCgg2iXt3XnhQSnX4vFKfWO-3vdWNV5HHBnSLWLQ&sensor=true&hl=pt) no-repeat" 38.7376583333,-9.1658583333&maptype=satellite&zoom=14&size=300x300&key=ABQIAAAAvQ9c8pqKsi8K2dzb7UM9MhS13VDmd70a9rmDETSCgg2iXt3XnhQSnX4vFKfWO-3vdWNV5HHBnSLWLQ&sensor=true&hl=pt) no-repeat

Comment: When you do `var_dump($h1['style']);`, what happens?

Answer (score 0):

substr()

```
echo substr($s, 0, strpos($s, '?') + 1) . substr($s, strpos($s, '&') + 1);
```

preg_replace()

```
echo preg_replace('~(\?center=.+?&)~', '?', $string);
```